# Does apple get any payment for the Wired magazine viewer App?

Tags: ipad

If you are subscribed to Wired magazine (paid subscription) you can download the [Wired iPad app](http://www.wired.com/magazine/ipad/) free and enter your Subscription # and view it on the iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Apple doesn't get any payment this way. There are a lot of newspapers, magazines etc. providing apps which allow electronic access. If they would offer in-app purchases Apple would take the usual 30%.